# string Interpolation in scala: how to apply it to object other than String?

Tags: string, scala, string-interpolation

```
case class T (a:String,b:String)
val x=T("a","b")

// I want to print the member a of x, so the expected value is a. but it doesn't work.
println(s"$x.a")
```

run the command, it print `T(a,b).a` instead.

```
scala> case class T (a:String,b:String)
defined class T

scala> val x=T("a","b")
x: T = T(a,b)

scala> println(s"$x.a")
T(a,b).a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap it in curly brackets:

```
scala> case class T (a:String,b:String)
defined class T

scala> val x=T("a","b")
x: T = T(a,b)

scala> println(s"$x.a")
T(a,b).a

scala> println(s"${x.a}")
a
```

From the [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html):

> String interpolators can also take arbitrary expressions. For example:
>
> println(s"1 + 1 = ${1 + 1}")
>   will print the string 1 + 1 = 2.
>
> Any arbitrary expression can be embedded in ${}.

Answer (score 3):

Try using curly brackets as follows,

```
println(s"${x.a}")
```